# .xcodeproj file issue after renaming

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I tried to change project name, but after that, a warning appears saying "Validate project settings Update to recommend settings". After that, I can't execute the project, and in left project explorer appears nothing but .xcodeproj file in red. I can build the project, but I can not run in the simulator.

Please, can you help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the "scanning for working copies" is directly related to your problem, that means it's looking for Git or Subversion files in your folders. It could however, have stalled the IDE, try restarting XCode.

Comment: I restarted the Xcode and still the same issue. I can't run the project, so it seems that the executable project is not set.thanks

Comment: Has the 'Scanning for working copies' message disappeared now?

Comment: Not, still there. Thanks

Comment: remove the .xcodeproj  from Xcode, and add it again.